# How to set API keys for non-authentication models in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am developing an inventory tracker for stores, where each store can have multiple outlets. I am using Django with the Django Rest Framework.

Each store is an authentication model. As such, it can manage its respective outlets and settings by logging into the system.

In the current state, each outlet uses the same token of the store model (provided by DRF) to connect and update inventory as sales are made. In my opinion, this creates a security vulnerability. For example, if a store has hundreds of outlets and one of the outlets' API key is exposed, all the outlets are exposed.

Is there some way to generate an authentication token for each outlet? This way the stores can manage and, if required, renew the token of each outlet.

Also, how would I validate this token in the DRF views and/or serializer?

Answer (score 1):

## Q1:

> Is there some way to generate an authentication token for each outlet?

Is full documented on [Customization](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#customization) section. For your code, for example, to have several keys for each outlet:

```py
# stores/models.py
from django.db import models
from rest_framework_api_key.models import AbstractAPIKey

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Outlet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        Store,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class OutletAPIKey(AbstractAPIKey):
    outlet = models.ForeignKey(
        Outlet,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="api_keys",
    )
```

You can [manage keys on admin panel](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#admin-panel).

## Q2:

> Also, how would I validate this token in the DRF views and/or serializer?

Following [programmatic usage](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#programmatic-usage) documentation should be something like this:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_api_key.models import APIKey
from rest_framework_api_key.permissions import HasAPIKey

from .models import Project

class ProjectListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey]

    def get(self, request):
        """Retrieve a project based on the request API key."""
        key = request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].split()[1]
        outlet_api_key = OutletAPIKey.objects.get_from_key(key)
        outlet = outlet_api_key.outlet
```